# cisco asa public server nat issue

Tags: networking, firewall, web-server, nat, cisco-asa

I have been tasked with some ASA configuration coming in a few weeks, and to test out some configuration options I have setup a web server on my local network which I would like to be able to access from via WAN with one of our static IP that ISP has given us.

```
Info:

ASA: 8.2

ASM: 6.2

Static Block from ISP: xx.152.125.240/29

Default Gateway (Static route to): xx.152.125.241

Ethernet 0/0 (outside) - WAN - xx.152.125.243 255.255.255.248

Ethernet 0/3 (inside) - LAN - 10.255.170.1 255.255.255.0
```

Attempt:

I first attempted to setup the NAT & ACL rules manually, without luck. So I deleted those and simply used the "Public Servers" feature setup like so:

```
Private Interface: inside

Private IP Address: 10.255.170.4

Service: tcp/8080, tcp/http, tcp/https

Public Interface: outside

Public IP Address: xx.152.125.244
```

This created the same exact rules I had setup manually the first time that hadn't worked, so I had little faith. Little to my surprise I could not hit the server via a browser. All other network functionality works great, and internally I can hit 10.255.170.4 server from a browser on a LAN workstation.

Troubleshooting:

I usually work via ASDM because I'm just starting to dig through the CLI references. I however dropped into CLI to perform the packet trace:

:: packet-tracer input outside tcp 1.2.3.4 8080 xx.152.125.244 8080

```
Phase: 1
Type: FLOW-LOOKUP
Subtype:
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
Found no matching flow, creating a new flow

Phase: 2
Type: UN-NAT
Subtype: static
Result: ALLOW
Config:
static (inside,outside) xx.152.125.244 10.255.170.4 netmask 255.255.255.255
nat-control
match ip inside host 10.255.170.4 outside any
static translation to xx.152.125.244
translate_hits = 0, untranslate_hits = 1
Additional Information:
NAT divert to egress interface inside
Untranslate xx.152.125.244/0 to 10.255.170.4/0 using netmask 255.255.255.255

Phase: 3
Type: ACCESS-LIST
Subtype: log
Result: ALLOW
Config:
access-group from_wan in interface outside
access-list from_wan extended permit tcp any host xx.152.125.244 object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_0
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_0 tcp
port-object eq www
port-object eq https
port-object eq 8080
Additional Information:

Phase: 4
Type: IP-OPTIONS
Subtype:
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:

Phase: 5
Type: VPN
Subtype: ipsec-tunnel-flow
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:

Phase: 6
Type: NAT
Subtype: rpf-check
Result: ALLOW
Config:
static (inside,outside) xx.152.125.244 10.255.170.4 netmask 255.255.255.255
nat-control
match ip inside host 10.255.170.4 outside any
static translation to xx.152.125.244
translate_hits = 0, untranslate_hits = 1
Additional Information:

Phase: 7
Type: NAT
Subtype: host-limits
Result: ALLOW
Config:
static (inside,outside) xx.152.125.244 10.255.170.4 netmask 255.255.255.255
nat-control
match ip inside host 10.255.170.4 outside any
static translation to xx.152.125.244
translate_hits = 0, untranslate_hits = 1
Additional Information:

Phase: 8
Type: IP-OPTIONS
Subtype:
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:

Phase: 9
Type: FLOW-CREATION
Subtype:
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
New flow created with id 350070, packet dispatched to next module

Result:
input-interface: outside
input-status: up
input-line-status: up
output-interface: inside
output-status: up
output-line-status: up
Action: allow
```

Question:

So given that the packet is not dropped, why would I not be able to hit the server via a browser to the public IP (xx.152.125.244:8080)? I feel like I'm missing something very simple but can't put my finger on it.

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Thanks.

EDIT: Here's the running-config

```
: Saved

:

ASA Version 8.2(1) 
!
names
name 10.255.170.0 XXXX_net
name xx.152.125.243 XXXX_wan description WAN
dns-guard
!
interface Ethernet0/0
 description ISP/WAN
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address XXXX_wan 255.255.255.248 
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 description LAN
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.255.170.1 255.255.255.0 
!
interface Management0/0
 description Management Interface
 shutdown
 nameif MGMT
 security-level 0
 ip address 172.16.1.1 255.255.255.0 
 management-only
!
boot system disk0:/asa821-k8.bin
ftp mode passive
dns domain-lookup outside
dns domain-lookup MGMT
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 domain-name XXXX.office
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
object-group protocol DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_1
 protocol-object ip
 protocol-object udp
 protocol-object tcp
object-group network bomgar-subnet
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_1 tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_2 tcp
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
object-group service DM_INLINE_SERVICE_1
 service-object ip 
 service-object icmp 
 service-object tcp eq www 
 service-object tcp eq https 
object-group service DM_INLINE_SERVICE_2
 service-object ip 
 service-object icmp 
 service-object tcp eq www 
 service-object tcp eq https 
object-group service DM_INLINE_TCP_0 tcp
 port-object eq 8080
 port-object eq www
 port-object eq https
access-list from_lan extended permit ip any any 
access-list from_lan extended permit gre any any 
access-list from_lan extended permit icmp any any 
access-list wan_xmit extended permit ip any any 
access-list from_wan extended permit tcp any host xx.152.125.244 object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_0 
access-list from_wan extended permit icmp any any 
access-list from_wan extended permit udp any any eq isakmp 
access-list from_wan extended permit tcp any any object-group DM_INLINE_TCP_1 
access-list from_wan extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_SERVICE_1 any interface outside inactive 
access-list from_wan extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_SERVICE_2 any xx.152.125.240 255.255.255.248 inactive 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip XXXX_net 255.255.255.0 XXXX_other_net 255.255.255.0 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip XXXX_net 255.255.255.0 10.255.170.240 255.255.255.240 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip any 10.255.170.240 255.255.255.240 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip any 10.255.170.192 255.255.255.192 
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip any 10.255.170.208 255.255.255.248 
access-list XXXX-RA_splitTunnelAcl standard permit XXXX_net 255.255.255.0 
access-list outside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip host XXXX_wan XXXX_net 255.255.255.0 
access-list VPN_RA_splitTunnelAcl standard permit XXXX_net 255.255.255.0 
access-list Bomgar extended permit object-group DM_INLINE_PROTOCOL_1 any host 10.255.170.169 
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm informational
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
mtu MGMT 1500
ip local pool RA-IP-Pool 10.255.170.240-10.255.170.250 mask 255.255.255.0
ip local pool NEW-POOL 10.255.170.220-10.255.170.230 mask 255.255.255.0
ip local pool WIN-POOL 10.255.170.210-10.255.170.215 mask 255.255.255.0
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
asdm image disk0:/asdm-621.bin
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
nat-control
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (outside) 0 access-list outside_nat0_outboundF
nat (inside) 0 access-list inside_nat0_outbound
nat (inside) 1 XXXX_net 255.255.255.0
static (inside,outside) xx.152.125.244 10.255.170.4 netmask 255.255.255.255 
access-group from_wan in interface outside
access-group wan_xmit out interface outside
access-group from_lan in interface inside
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 xx.152.125.241 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL 
aaa authorization command LOCAL 
http server enable
http XXXX_other_net 255.255.255.0 inside
http XXXX_net 255.255.255.0 inside
http 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 MGMT
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-MD5 esp-aes-256 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-SHA esp-des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-DES-MD5 esp-des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-MD5 esp-aes-192 esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-MD5 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-256-SHA esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-192-SHA esp-aes-192 esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-AES-128-MD5 esp-aes esp-md5-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set TRANS_ESP_3DES_SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec transform-set TRANS_ESP_3DES_SHA mode transport
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac 
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 28800
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 4608000
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set pfs group1
crypto dynamic-map SYSTEM_DEFAULT_CRYPTO_MAP 65535 set transform-set ESP-AES-128-SHA ESP-AES-128-MD5 ESP-AES-192-SHA ESP-AES-192-MD5 ESP-AES-256-SHA ESP-AES-256-MD5 ESP-3DES-SHA ESP-3DES-MD5 ESP-DES-SHA ESP-DES-MD5 TRANS_ESP_3DES_SHA
crypto isakmp policy 10
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto isakmp nat-traversal 200
crypto isakmp ipsec-over-tcp port 10000 
telnet timeout 5
ssh XXXX_net 255.255.255.0 inside
ssh XXXX_other_net 255.255.255.0 inside
ssh 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0 MGMT
ssh timeout 30
ssh version 2
console timeout 0
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
webvpn
group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol svc 

[usernames-ommited]

tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup general-attributes
 address-pool RA-IP-Pool
 address-pool NEW-POOL
 address-pool WIN-POOL
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ppp-attributes
 no authentication chap
!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect netbios 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect pptp 
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context 
Cryptochecksum:2a15a897244d95160b7f34f2b8a1c8f6
: end
```

Comment: Could it be a DNS issue?  A routing issue on the inside?  Is the server's default gateway set to the inside of the firewall?  Without seeing the ASA configuration, we're just guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can look into DNS but doubt it. The server's default gateway is the ASA inside interface. I can post config soon.

Comment: Also look at the log when you access the server (turn logging on if it isn't).

Comment: Yeah logs don't show any traffic for either public or private IP. Also tried to capture packets on each and couldn't see any packets. Something is very odd, because if I pull the server from the inside interface and connect it in parallel with the outside interface the server gets hit just fine with the public IP. So I know the traffic is coming in on the public IP.

Comment: Why do you have the nat(outside) command?  If you see nothing on the packet captures then 1) you're doing it wrong, or 2) data is not reaching the ASA - maybe there's a problem elsewhere (switch port)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fooling around with this for a about a week I got the ISP involved and come to find out it was a routing issue with the ISP.

Once notified everything was updated and configuration of the ASA was simple and straightforward.